# jQuery passing multiple parameters via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli, parameters

Using jQuery, I can use the code below to send 1 parameter via ajax, and return the requested data.

My javascript file is called:  globals.js

```
 $('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
   var port = $('#port').val();  // single parameter passed from index.php
   if($.trim(port) != '')
   {
     $.post('api/summary.php', {port: port}, function(data){
       $('#content').html(data);
     });
   }
 });
```

Here are a few INPUT fields located in a file called index.php

```
 <input type="text" id="port" name="port" />
 <input type="text" id="voyage" name="voyage" />
 <input type="text" id="rep" name="rep" />
 // quite a few more input fields and select options as well

 <button type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton">Submit</button>

 <script src="js/globals.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   // included javascript file above
```

So when the user enters a PORT and clicks submit, the jQuery above executes and takes the PORT and, via ajax call, sends it the PHP script called: summary.php

```
 <?php
   include("../include/database.php");

   $_SESSION['where'] = "";
   $port = $_POST['port'];
   $voyage = $_POST['voyage'];
   $rep = $_POST['rep'];
   // more variables follow;

   // at this point, I can echo port and return in to the page, 
      or use it in a query, and return the data in a table if necessary

   echo $port;  // passed from jquery
   echo $voyage; // cannot pass from jquery
   echo $rep;  // cannot pass from jquery
   // and so on....

   ?>
```

I can display the content (which right now is only PORT) in the $('#content').html(data) indicated in the jQuery above.

But what I need to do is to be able to have the jQuery accept multiple parameters and pass them to my PHP script.  This is where I am stuck.

I know the issue lies in my jQuery above.

So my question is:  How do I pass 1 or more parameters all without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add to the array -

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
    var port = $('#port').val();  // single parameter passed from index.php
    var voyage = $('#voyage').val();
    // add other values here
    if($.trim(port) != '')
    {
        $.post('api/summary.php', {port: port, voyage: voyage /* add other values separated by commas */}, function(data){
```

Comment: So simple, but what will happen if they leave, say PORT blank and enter VOYAGE instead?  Will that throw everything off?

Comment: No, the value for PORT will be sent as a blank.

Comment: So for every available variable that I have in the form, I can just add it to the jquery?  You're telling me it's that simple???  Haha....I will attempt this and let you know if I was successful.  Thank you for your help, good sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post( "api/summary.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm"} , function(data){
       $('#content').html(data);
     });
```

Something like this? Just attach the extra data, separated by a comma.

Comment: Same question to you as above: what will happen if the user enters something for VOYAGE but not for PORT?

Comment: The value sent will be empty.

Comment: Gave you an upvote because your answer was the same as Jay Blanchard's answer, and it was successful. Thank you for commenting.